# PHP | Аргументы функции переменной длинны

Tags: php, функции

Как правильно объявить функцию с одним параметром, принимающую массив одинакового типа элементов?

---

#### Первый вариант

Использование единственного аргумента типа **array**.

```
/**
 * @param string[] $dependencies
 */
public function setDependencies (array $dependencies) : void
{
    $this->dependencies = $dependencies;
}
```

#### Второй вариант

Использование аргументов функции переменной длинны.

```
/**
 * @param string ...$dependencies
 */
public function setDependencies (string ...$dependencies) : void
{
    $this->dependencies = $dependencies;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setDependencies(array $dependencies)` - в данном случае вы, передаете 1 аргумент с типом `array`, где использоваться будет так:

```
setDependencies([1,2,3]);
```

А вот в случае с `setDependencies (string ...$dependencies)`, вы задействуете оператор `and so on` (и так далее...) и сможете передавать неограниченное количество аргументов типа `string` и только:

```
setDependencies('str1', 'str2', 'str3');
```

Что собственно тоже является массивом.
Если внутри функции, сделать так:

```
var_dump($dependencies);
```

То вывод будет такой:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "str1"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "str2"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "str3"
}
```

Также можно передавать неограниченное количество массивов, если тип будет `array`, то есть так: `setDependencies(array ...$dependencies)`, в данном случае мы, сможем передавать только массивы и ничего более (ну, а в массив, можно поместить, что угодно):

```
setDependencies(['str1', 1], ['str2', 2], ['str3', 3]);
```

И вывод уже будет такой:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "str1"
    [1]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "str2"
    [1]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "str3"
    [1]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

Но можно и вовсе не указывать тип и передавать любые аргументы, с любым типом.
И кстати, тип `void` указывать не обязательно, так-как, функция которая ничего не возвращает и так имеет тип `void` - по этому, в данный момент - это избыточный код.

Comment: `void` - скорее нужен для того, чтобы различные `IDE` понимали что это за функция.

Comment: @Manitikyl, они и так прекрасно понимают.

Comment: `NetBeans` к примеру понимает лучше. + Для автодокументирования это полезно, вообще лучше не лениться и писать `void`.

Comment: @Manitikyl, Это не обязательно, но если так этого хочется, можно и написать. У пыха. по умолчанию, функции, которые ничего не возвращают, имеют тип `void`.

Comment: Ну конкретно в данном случае да, необязательно. Но вообще есть моменты где без `void` никак.